# Named previously unnamed branch

Tags: mercurial

It seems naming a previously unnamed branch doesn't really work out. It creates a nasty multiple heads problem that I can't find a solution for.

Here is the workflow...

UserA starts working on feature that they expect to be small, so they just start working(off the `default` branch). The change turns out to be a large project and will need multiple contributors. So UserA issues... `hg branch "Feature1"` and continues working, committing locally s needed.

UserA then pulls down the changes from the central repo so he can push.

At this point, why does `hg heads` return **3** heads? It shows 2 for `default` and 1 for `Feature1`. The first head for `default` is the latest change by another user on the branch(irrelevant).  The second `default` head is the commit prior to the `hg branch "Feature1"` commit.

The  **central repository has rules enforced so that only 1 head per branch is allowed**, so forcing a push isn't an option.  The repo doesn't want multiple heads on the `default` branch.

UserA should be able to push these changes so that other users can see the `Feature1` branch and help out. I can't seem to find a way to "correct" this. I don't think I can re-write the branch of the initial commits for the feature, before it was a named branch.

I know the initial changes before the named branch are technically on the default branch, but does that mean they will be heads until that `Feature1` branch is merged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution without have to re-clone and merge changes in. I prefer this method mainly for historical purposes as I think it's valuable information on what happened with the feature (aka it started small and then was re-thought to be larger etc..)

In my example, UserA should update to the unwanted head on `default` and close that branch of default, as it is unwanted. This will leave 2 heads one for `default` and one for `Feature1` as expected.

```
hg update -r X // X is the rev of the unwanted head.
hg commit --close-branch -m "Moved to Named Branch Feature1, cleaning up initial work"
```

Then update to the `Feature1` branch, push and continue working.

Another workflow is almost the same except the UserA decided to push `Feature1` for others to help and `default` has not been moved forward by anyone else. The local repo only has 2 heads and the user could push, but UserA does NOT want to just push as the tip of `default` would now be the changeset that really "belongs" to `Feature1`.

UserA should update to the latest, unwanted changeset of `defaul`t. Then revert the `default` back to the revision before UserA starting working.

```
hg update default
hg revert -r Y // Y is the changeset before UserA started working on the feature
hg commit -m "Reverting changes that now exist in Feature1 branch"
```

Then update to the `Feature1` branch, push and continue working.

Comment: When I wrote my answer, I understood from your question that your main concern was to have the changes in the local repository that were on the `default` branch "moved" onto the `feature` branch.  Since that's not the case, merging the two `default` heads is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're seeing two heads on the `default` branch in the local repo is because, after the most recent common ancestor, the changesets in the central repo have nothing in common with the changesets in the local repo.

To solve your problem:

1. Create a new local clone of the central repo at whatever revision you want (it will probably be easier if you use the most recent common ancestor).

   ```
   hg clone -r common_ancestor central local2
   ```
2. Export the changes from the first local repo.  Note the colon after `first_local_change` to get all the changes in that repo.

   ```
   cd local1
   hg export -r first_local_change: > ../local1.patch
   ```
3. Go to the new local repository, create the `feature` branch to import the changes into, then import them:

   ```
   cd ../local2
   hg branch feature
   hg import ../local1.patch
   ```

   `hg import` has an option to use the branch information in the patch file, but it's disabled by default.

At this point, you can continue using the new local repo in the original one's place.  Also, I would double check to make sure that everything is as it should be in the new repo.

Answer (score 1):

We found this to be a very big problem with our team (doing branch-per-feature) and ultimately stopped the hgweb.cgi script working (HTTP 414 Request too Long).

Answer (score -1):

from `hg help heads`: `hg heads` with no args will show branch heads, which by definition are changesets that have no children on the same branch. `hg heads --topo` should give you result you need in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Don't go via the central repository. Just have your developers pull from each other.